# How to combine all possible N boolean values?

Tags: boolean-computation

Is there any simpler formula than

```
Tuples[{False, True}, 3]
```

to generate tuples of all combinations of boolean values?

Comment: In what way do you want it to be simpler?  That looks like a very simple and efficient way to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

As said in comments, that's an efficient way of generating combinations. If you want to *do something* with them, *BooleanTable* is pretty neat:

```
TableForm[
 BooleanTable[{{a, b, c}, And[a, b, c], Or[a, b, c], Xor[a, b, c], Xnor[a, b, c]}, {a, b, c}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Vars", "And", "Or", "Xor", "Xnor"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: that is neat! +1:)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another way to this goal:

```
IntegerDigits[#, 2, 3] & /@ Range[2^3] /. {1 -> "True", 0 -> "False"}
```

;-)